# How to make the form submit with normal button?

Tags: forms, button, post, serialization, submit

Here is the code I used.
With a click function, I made the POST action to the controller..

```
$('#btn1').click(function (e) {

    $.post($('#frmLogin').attr('action'), $('#frmLogin').serialize(), function (data) {

    });
});


@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", new { Model }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmLogin" }))
{ 
    <input type="button" id="btn1"/>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function on clicking your normal button

```
    function form_submit()
    {
            document.getElementById('formID').submit();
    }
or use this jquery



 $( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#frmLogin" ).submit();
   });
```

Comment: Will the form get submitted on clicking ENTER key?

Comment: it won't work.. i got the solution..
I fired a trigegr..
$("#txtPassword").keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("#btnSubmit").trigger("click");
   }
});